# Syntax for attributes for constructors

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the proper location for an attribute specifier for a constructor? The standard doesn't seem to distinguish constructor in any special way but the normal locations lead to warnings from GCC and Clang.

```
struct test {
    [[gnu::nonnull]] test (char * arg);     // gcc-6.3 ok, clang error.
    test [[gnu::nonnull]] (signed * arg);   // gcc/clang error
    test (unsigned * arg) [[gnu::nonnull]]; // gcc warning, clang error.
};
```

I use the second for other functions with no issues.

Is this a bug in gcc and clang?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug. `test [[gnu::nonnull]] (signed * arg);` should be valid.

Comment: The first one is accepted by both compiler: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e70b7116615c3895)

Comment: The other 2 produce errors or warnings.

Comment: Clang trunk does indeed take the second.

I've created a bug report for GCC:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79458